# is there a way to listen to store changes in react-redux and then navigate to a new page using the data from the newly created item in the store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am having a really hard time putting a handle on an item added to the store without cheating( returning the new conversation once it is created on the server ).

My goal is to create a "Conversation" and then do other stuff with it but I cant seem to do it for some reason (navigate to a url with the conversation id )

here is my conversationsAction.js component that creates a conversation.
I KNOW i can just return the created conversation after dispatching the action to at the to the store but i know that can be the best way to do it.

```
// src/actions/conversationsActions.js

import TextExtractorUtil from "../util/TextExtractor";

// Action types
export const CREATE_CONVERSATION_SUCCESS = 'CREATE_CONVERSATION_SUCCESS';
export const CREATE_CONVERSATION_FAILURE = 'CREATE_CONVERSATION_FAILURE';
export const DELETE_CONVERSATION_SUCCESS = 'DELETE_CONVERSATION_SUCCESS';
export const DELETE_CONVERSATION_FAILURE = 'DELETE_CONVERSATION_FAILURE';

export const FETCH_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_CONVERSATIONS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_CONVERSATIONS_FAILURE';


const baseUrl = '/api/conversation/';
const textExtractorUtil = new TextExtractorUtil();

// Action creators
export const createConversation = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  console.log('createConversation() [action]')
  try {
    const { token } = getState().auth;

    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}create_conversation`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,

      },
      body: null,
    });

    const data = await response.json();

    const formattedConversations = [data.conversation].map((conversation) => ({
      ...conversation,
      created_on: `${conversation.created_on}`, 
      updated_on: `${conversation.updated_on}`, 
      _id: textExtractorUtil.mongodbIdExtractor(conversation._id)
    }));

    // Dispatch a success action with the new conversation data
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_CONVERSATION_SUCCESS,
      payload: formattedConversations[0],
    });

    // return formattedConversations   // THIS IS WHERE I CAN CHEAT
  } catch (error) {
    // Dispatch a failure action with the error message
    // console.log('error', error);
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_CONVERSATION_FAILURE,
      payload: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

after doing some digging around the web i found that I can do store.subscribe to manipulate the item added. the issue is that THAT object is in store.js, I need to use it in the FormInput.js file.
here is what my store.js file looks like ::

note: its the store.subscribe that I want in another component if possible

```
// store.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import authReducer from './reducers/authReducer';
import conversationsReducer from './reducers/conversationsReducer'; 
import conversationMessagesReducer from './reducers/conversationMessageReducer';
import chatAppSideMenuReducer from './reducers/chatAppSideMenuReducer';
import filesReducer from './reducers/filesReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  conversations: conversationsReducer,
  conversationMessages: conversationMessagesReducer,
  chatAppSideMenu: chatAppSideMenuReducer,
  files: filesReducer,

  // Add other reducers here if needed
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
store.subscribe(() => {
  // Access the updated state to get the new conversation data
  const updatedConversations = store.getState().conversations.conversations;
  // You can now access the newly created conversation, which should be at the end of the array
  const newConversation = updatedConversations[updatedConversations.length - 1];

  // Do something with the new conversation data
  console.log('New Conversation:', newConversation);
});

export default store;
```

is there a way to do a store subscription or something along those lines to capture the new object?

I know I can also use UseEffect(  ()=> {},[conversations] ) but i wanted to ask if there is a cleaner way of doing this.

this is the component where I want to add the handle to deal with the newly created conversation (see handleSubmit function )::

```
// FormInput.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStore } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../../../../../store';
import styles from './FormInput.module.css';
import { useSnackbar } from "../../.../../../../../../shared/snack-bar/SnackBarContext";
import { createConversation } from '../../../../../../actions/conversationsActions';
const FormInput = React.forwardRef(({ style, files, createConversation, conversations }, ref) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { showSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState('');
  const { chatId } = useParams();
  let isNewConversation = chatId === 'new';


  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // check if there is a file
    const conversationFiles = files.filter((file) => file.conversation_id === chatId);

    if (conversationFiles.length == 0) {
      return showSnackbar('Please select a pdf to get started', 'red', 3000);
    }
    if (newMessage == '') {
      return showSnackbar('Please enter a question', 'red', 3000);
    }
    isNewConversation = chatId === 'new';

    await createConversation();
    // ADD CODE TO LISTEN TO NEW CONVERSATION CREATED HERE
  }





  return (

    <form className={`${styles['message-input-form']}   ${style}`} ref={ref}>
      <input
        type="text"
        defaultValue={newMessage} // Use defaultValue instead of value
        placeholder="  Type your message..."
        className={styles.input} // Apply the input style from the CSS module
        onChange={(event) => setNewMessage(event.target.value)} // Add onChange handler
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit} className={styles.button}>
        Send
      </button>
    </form>
  );
});


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  token: state.auth.token,
  conversations: state.conversations.conversations,
  conversationMessages: state.conversationMessages.messages,
  isChatAppSideMenuOpen: state.chatAppSideMenu.isChatAppSideMenuOpen,
  files: state.files.files



});

const mapActionsToProps = {
  // actions
  createConversation,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(FormInput);
```

=========================

After a lot of research and CHATGPTing, i realized that I can use a middleware to put a handle on the newly added Conversation. now the issue is that I cant travel to the new page from that middleware because you can only use hooks in components ...

I updated the store.js with the following::

```
// store.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import authReducer from './reducers/authReducer';
import conversationsReducer from './reducers/conversationsReducer'; 
import conversationMessagesReducer from './reducers/conversationMessageReducer';
import chatAppSideMenuReducer from './reducers/chatAppSideMenuReducer';
import filesReducer from './reducers/filesReducer'
import conversationMiddleware from './middleware/conversationMiddleware';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  conversations: conversationsReducer,
  conversationMessages: conversationMessagesReducer,
  chatAppSideMenu: chatAppSideMenuReducer,
  files: filesReducer,

  // Add other reducers here if needed
});

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, conversationMiddleware),
);

export default store;
```

here is the middleware conversationMiddleware ( as you can see i commented out the functions because i can use them here )::

```
// captureNewConversationMiddleware.js


// import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
// import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { useSnackbar } from "../shared/snack-bar/SnackBarContext";

import { CREATE_CONVERSATION_SUCCESS } from '../actions/conversationsActions';

const conversationMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  // const navigate = useNavigate();
  // const { showSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  // const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState('');
  // const { chatId } = useParams();
  if (action.type === CREATE_CONVERSATION_SUCCESS) {
    const { payload } = action; 
    // console.log('New Conversation:', chatId);

  }

  return next(action);
};

export default conversationMiddleware;
```

How can i create a conversation and then get its id so that I can go to a website?